# É correto usar a palavra garage além de garagem?

Tags: gramática, vocabulário

Comumente utilizamos a palavra garagem, entretanto alguns lugares afirmam que é correto usar a palavra garage também, mas afinal é correto ou não?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A palavra pode trazer alguma ambiguidade:

- Efetivamente, [*garage*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/garage) pode constar no dicionário, mas principalmente como um estrangeirismo francês, e pronuncia-se até de maneira diferente (`gàràge`).
- Sem ser pelo estrangeirismo, a pronúncia de *garage* pode surgir através de uma evolução fonética da palavra por via popular, dentro de algum dialecto. Em Portugal, pronunciar *garage* ou *vezinha* é considerado relativamente comum em algumas aldeias e regiões.

Com isto, embora não incorreto, a palavra *garagem* é favorecida face a *garage*.

Answer (score 7):

O meu dicionário (Aurélio) tem uma entrada para a ortografia *garage*:

> **garage**
> Substantivo feminino
>
> 1. V. *garagem*

Então a palavra *garage* parece de ser um sinónimo de *garagem*. Porém, veremos os usos mais comuns da mesma:

O [CRPC](http://www.clul.ul.pt/en/researcher/183-reference-corpus-of-contemporary-portuguese-crpc) (Corpus de Referência do Português Contemporâneo) apresenta:

- *garage*    128 resultados
- *garagem*  1008 resultados

No entanto, na verdade, os resultados de *garage* são principalmente:

- parte de um nome (por exemplo, "Paradise Garage");
- uma palavra inglesa (por exemplo, "Underground garage");
- ou se referem  ao gênero musical de *garage* (house/rock, por exemplo "ritmos garage").

Por isso os resultados reais são:

- *garage*    <10 resultados
- *garagem*  1008 resultados

E dos 10 resultados restantes alguns podem ter erros de ortografia. Quantitativamente, a ortografia ***garage* é provavelmente considerada incorreta** (quando usada no sentido de *garagem*), e correta quando se refere ao gênero musical de *garage* (house/rock).

Comment: (The question was written in Portuguese, so I tried to translate my [English post](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/revisions/247/1). Please help me by correcting my Portuguese. Thank you!)

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é correto, aparece em mais de um dicionário como sinônimo de Garagem.

Comment: Não percebo porque votaram negativamente esta resposta. Se tivessem comentado, ela poderia ser melhorada; mas não o fizeram.

Comment: @ANeves Esta reposta sugere que posso usar qualquer forma. Mas realmente, a forma "garage" não é usada como sinônimo (como tentei mostrar na minha reposta). Então parece que esta reposta não é tal informativo.